# Print the same values for 10 times in active cell with comma separated

Tags: excel, vba

I want to print a  specific value in a cell for 10 or more times with a comma using a command button. Can anyone explain how to write macro for this?

As I click the command button the value should print desired times in the active cell. The data is very bulk so manually its very difficult to get into single cell and type it.

Comment: @MattTaylor I am very new to macro domain. I am looking for the experts advice.

Comment: And I think that's a great thing to do, but there are plenty of experts who have written great tutorials all over the internet. SO isn't just a place to get any old questions answered, that's why duplicates are removed. It's intended as a place to come with harder questions that you couldn't answer on your own

Comment: @MattTaylor Matt, I digged this query in StackOF, but I couldn't find. As I mentioned I am new for Macro, thought of this is the best place for learning..!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into your Commandbutton_Click event handler:

```
Dim strValueToPrint as String, strOutput as String
Dim intRepeatCount as Integer, i as Integer

strValueToPrint = "1" 'Change this to be the value that you want to repeat
for i = 1 to intRepeatCount
    strOutput = strOutput & strValueToPrint & ","
Next
Activecell.Value = strOutput
```

Comment: Thanks, the count works good but with little extra stuffs. Actually I have two text boxes, in the first box i am going to enter the value which is to be printed and in the second box i am entering the repeat value. So, I turned your code to like this:

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
strValueToPrint = TextBox1.Value 'Value to be printed
intRepeatCount = TextBox2.Value 'Value: number of times to be repeated
For i = 1 To intRepeatCount
    strOutput = strOutput & strValueToPrint & ","
Next
ActiveCell.Value = strOutput
End Sub

Comment: When I tried this code, for the first instance the values printed exactly as i needed, but when I Change the values in both text boxes it is taking the previous values and printing. Can you help me for this problem?

Comment: Do you mean it is keeping what was in the text boxes before you changed them? If so you'll need to step through the code using F8 and mouse over the strValueToPrint variable to check what value it assumes at each point. I'm not sure how it would be getting the wrong values if the `strValueToPrint = TextBox1.Value` code runs after you have changed the TextBox1 value.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Yeah It is taking the previous value!!! Anyhow I will check it. If there is need I will need suggestion from you. Please.

Comment: Matt, your suggestion worked excellently. Thanks a lot. I made these changes for the code:`code`
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
strValueToPrint = TextBox1.Value 'Value i.e., to be printed
intRepeatCount = TextBox2.Value 'Count value
For i = 1 To intRepeatCount
    strOutput = strOutput & strValueToPrint & ","
    ActiveCell.Value = strOutput
Next
strOutput = "" 'assigning the value to null, so that the previous value is ignored
ActiveCell.Activate
End Sub